# jQuery: How to get all emails with Can Edit option selected?

Tags: jquery

```
   <table >
        <tr>
            <td>test1@gmail.com</td>
            <td>
                <select name="limit">
                    <option selected="selected">Can Edit</option>
                    <option>Can View</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <i class="icon-remove"></i>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test2@gmail.com</td>
            <td>
                <select name="limit">
                    <option>Can Edit</option>
                    <option selected="selected">Can View</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <i class="icon-remove"></i>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Consider the above HTML, how to get all emails that with `Can Edit` option selected using jQuery? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*try this :    ( shows every mail which has a option selected inside + CAN EDIT)*

```
$("tr:has(td:eq(1):has(option:selected:contains('Can Edit')))").each(function (i,n){

  alert($(this).find("td:first").text());

})
```

alerts :

```
test1@gmail.com 
test22221@gmail.com
```

http://jsbin.com/aroxuw/4/edit

Answer (score 3):

```
var emails = [];

$('option:selected').each(function()
{
  if ( $(this).html() == 'Can Edit' )
    emails.push( $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').html() );
});
```

Comment: `.parent()` should be `.parents()`

Comment: should also be `option:selected`

Comment: You know what, I take it back. don't use `.parents()`, use `.closest()`. The performance hit can be daunting eventually. `.parents()` traverses the DOM to the top, taking a collection of each parent object on the way and pushing it into a temporary object to filter it against after it's done, while closest simply moves up the tree and matches the first element it finds.

Comment: Can we please get an accepted answer over here?! I feel like we worked too hard for you to not get your 15 reputation!